# Hi resolution in virtual consoles with nvidia legacy driver on Debian 10.1

Tags: drivers, debian, graphics-card

I have installed nvidia-legacy-340xx-driver from contrib repository in Debian 10.1. The driver is working but I have low resolution in virtual consoles. With nouveau driver the resolution was the monitor native resolution 1920x1080.
I want that resolution with nvidia legacy driver.
I have found some articles about uvesafb, but the maximum supported resolution is 800x600.
Is it possibly to have hi resolution with nvidia legacy driver and how?

Comment: Do you really need the legacy driver? That's for very old cards only. And if yours is really old and `nouveau` works better, why not use it?

Comment: Yes, my card is very old and I have to use nvidia legacy driver. Nvidia driver is better for graphics, and noveau for text.
I must find a way to blacklist nvidia driver, when I need text mode and then blacklist nouveau, when I need graphics. For now I cannot find better solution.